# How to pass the user image(fetched from Facebook profile) from navbar to another activity

Tags: android, image, android-intent, uri

This is my Activity 1

```
final Intent ridesameIntent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
    TextView userText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.username);
    ImageView userImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profile_pic);
    String userNameMessage = userText.getText().toString();
    String userPicMessage = userImage.toString();
    ridesameIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE_USERNAME,userNameMessage);
    ridesameIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE_USERPIC,userPicMessage);
     startActivity(ridesameIntent);
```

This is Activity 2

```
 Intent userDetail = getIntent();
    String userPicMessage = userDetail.getStringExtra(Activity1.EXTRA_MESSAGE_USERPIC);
    String userNameMessage = userDetail.getStringExtra(Activity1.EXTRA_MESSAGE_USERNAME);
    TextView userdetail1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.username_scroll);
    ImageView userdetail2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profile_pic_scroll);
    userdetail1.setText(userNameMessage);
    userdetail2.setImageURI(Uri.parse(userPicMessage));
```

I have tried passing the uri but getting no results in passing the user pic
also for help here is the code which fetches user profile from Facebook and sets it into the navbar of Activity 1

```
public void setUserProfile(String jsondata) {

    try {
        response = new JSONObject(jsondata);
        user_email.setText(response.get("email").toString());
        user_name.setText(response.get("name").toString());
        profile_pic_data = new JSONObject(response.get("picture").toString());
        profile_pic_url = new JSONObject(profile_pic_data.getString("data"));

        Picasso.with(this).load(profile_pic_url.getString("url"))
                .into(user_picture);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

So please suggest me how can i get the image to activity 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`profile_pic_url.getString("url")` extract this value into a variable  and pass it as your intent extra and then load it with a Picasso in your second activity like in your `setUserProfile` method.

EDIT.
So in your `setUserProfile(String jsondata)` method on this line `Picasso.with(this).load(profile_pic_url.getString("url")).into(user_picture);` in your load() method you're extracting an url string from a `JSONObject` by calling `profile_pic_url.getString("url")`. You can create a field from that statement via Right click -> Refactor -> Extract -> Field... And then call put it as extra to your intent by calling `ridesameIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE_USERPIC, fieldNameThatYouExtracted);`

Then in your second activity call 
`Picasso.with(this).load(userPicMessage).into(userPicMessage);` instead of `userdetail2.setImageURI(Uri.parse(userPicMessage));`

After that you can learn how to simplify json deserialization using GSON library [Leveraging the Gson Library](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Leveraging-the-Gson-Library)

Comment: I tried the above way but it is not working,any other alternative?

Comment: With few tweaks i got the image in the second activity but when i send the path to the database(as it is from Facebook) i am getting the image view path and not the url for the image like i use to get in my first activity 'final String picture = profile_pic_url.getString("url")'

Comment: `String userPicMessage = userDetail.getStringExtra(Activity1.EXTRA_MESSAGE_USERPIC);` in this method you should get your path that you passed from first activity. So you have to save this string variable to the database.

Answer (score 1):

Hello this is my code by which i get rid of this problem

In first Activity

```
 Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
                    Bundle mBundle = new Bundle();
                           mBundle.putParcelable("pic", profile);
                    Intent loginint = new Intent(MainActivity.this,DashBoard.class);
                   loginint.putExtra("email",email);
                    loginint.putExtras(mBundle);

                    startActivity(loginint);
                    finish();
```

And in Second Activity where u want to show that Image

```
    Intent intent = getIntent(); 
   Bundle mBundle =intent.getExtras();
    Profile  profile;

    if (mBundle != null) {
       profile = (Profile) mBundle.getParcelable("pic");
    } else {
        profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
    }

    Picasso.with(DashBoard.this)
            .load(profile.getProfilePictureUri(400, 400).toString())
            .into(mfbimage);
```

here mfbimage is  object of ImageView where u want to show that Profile Picture.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the image Bitmap through the intent to the second activity as it implements the Parcelable interface.

```
Bitmap profileBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)user_picture.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
ridesameIntent.putExtra("profilePic", profileBitmap);
```

And on the other end :

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) intent.getParcelableExtra("profilePic");
```

Comment: This is really helpful but what if i want to send the image url to the json database and then in a later step retrieve it by using picasso.Then this Bitmap stuff is not helpful.